# Configuring standalone.xml in Wildfly for redirect root(/) to sub directory

Tags: wildfly-8

How to redirect root path to subpath?

e.g.
http://test.com:9090/ -> http://test.com:9090/portal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer version Wildfly, we can used rewrite in undertow:

```
<filter-ref name="root-redirect" predicate='regex(pattern="^/$", value="%U", full-match=true)' />

<rewrite name="root-redirect" redirect="true" target="/xxx" />
```

Answer (score -2):

If you only need redirect rather than rewrite, you can create ROOT.war and have have single index page with redirect

Comment: Thanks! I will try on this way. 